# Laravel Packages & Migrations

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am new to working with Laravel, I am making an activity logger at the momement, for a web applicaiton, I have created a package to wrap all this functionality up so it can be ported from project to project via composer.

The package is reliant on a couple of database tables, I was just wondering where the migrations should live? I have the migrations folder in the main root database folder but, I also have the migrations folder in my Package?

If I am to use the migrations folder in my package how to I create migrations there?

`php artisan migrate:make create_users_table --table --create` would create the migration in the main app, but I want it in the package.

Any advice of guidance would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just simply add `--path` to your package migration folder. Here is the example :

```
php artisan migrate:make create_users_table --table --create --path=workbench/vendor/package/src/migrations
```